# How to get Mypy to recognize a class's protocol membership within a Callable?

Tags: python, mypy, protocol-oriented

Mypy properly recognizes a class's adherence to a protocol when the protocol is used as a simple parameter to a type-annotated function. However, when I have a function requiring a callable parameter using that protocol, Mypy misses the user class's protocol membership.

Am I misusing Mypy's protocol pattern, or is this something simply not supported by Mypy at the moment?

(I have seen the thread about Mypy having trouble with Callables [that get assigned to a class](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/708).. so this may be a known behavior)

```
from typing_extensions import Protocol
from typing import Callable

class P(Protocol) :
    def foo(self) -> None : ...


def requires_P(protocol_member : P) -> None : 
    protocol_member.foo()

def requires_P_callable(protocol_member : P, function: Callable[[P],None]) -> None :
    function(protocol_member)



class C :
    def foo(self) :
        print("bar")

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    c = C()

    def call_foo(c: C) -> None: 
        c.foo()

    requires_P(c) 
                # mypy is fine with this

    requires_P_callable(c, call_foo) 
                # mypy complains : 
                #       Argument 2 to "requires_P_callable" has incompatible type "Callable[[C], None]"; expected "Callable[[P], None]"
```

Comment: it looks like a bug in `mypy`

Comment: I am not sure: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/#covariance-and-contravariance Please read about co-variance and contra-variance of Callables.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I wasn't aware of the contravariance of arguments in Callables, so this has been extremely helpful to me. Even though C isn't strictly a subtype of P in my example I imagine the co/contra -variance has something to do with how Mypy checks protocol patterns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If replace definition of call_foo with:

`def call_foo(c: P) -> None:
    c.foo()`

error disappears and program continue to work... The situation is the same if stop using Protocol and make C a child of P.

Second workaround is:

```
from typing import Callable, Protocol, TypeVar

_TP = TypeVar('_TP', bound='P')


class P(Protocol):
    def foo(self) -> None:
        ...


class C:

    def foo(self) -> None:
        print("foo")


def requires_P_callable(prot: _TP, func: Callable[[_TP], None]) -> None:
    func(prot)


def call_foo(c: C) -> None:
    c.foo()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    c = C()
    requires_P_callable(c, call_foo)
```

Comment: Many thanks for all the solutions. The TypeVar approach worked well for me.  I was hesitating to use `def call_foo(c: P)`[...] , since I have different variations of `call_foo` for each class implementing `P` in my project. Now that I somewhat understand what causes this I feel I can make a more informed choice among the various workarounds.